# Stored procedure to find first day of month when an End Date and number of month differences is given in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to write a SQL Server stored procedure calculate the first day of month when the user provides the Till date and number of month differences from start month.

The parameters to the stored procedure will be

```
@TillDate DATE, @NoOfMonthFromStartDate INT
```

Example:

```
@TillDate = '2015-10-31', @NoOfMonthFromStartDate = 5
```

The result should be like:

```
01-10-2015
01-09-2015
01-08-2015
01-07-2015
01-06-2015
```

Please provide your valuable help.

Comment: Please provide your valuable attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tally table to generate N number of dates

```
DECLARE @TillDate DATE = '20151031'
DECLARE @NoOfMonthFromStartDate INT = 5

;WITH Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@NoOfMonthFromStartDate)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, -(N-1), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @TillDate), 0))
FROM Tally
```

---

If `@TillDate` is always the end of a month:

```
;WITH Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@NoOfMonthFromStartDate)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, -N, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @TillDate))
FROM Tally
```

Comment: Thank you @FelixPamittan